# jQuery animation cutting images in Webkit browsers, not Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari

The site in question is http://bit.ly/7MeLwc

In the honor roll section, when I view the next set of images in Chrome/Safari, the images seem to be cut up, until I mouse over them. But on Firefox, it works fine!

What could be causing such behavior in Webkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a genuine bono-fide webkit bug. Not your fault, your code is correct, responsibility here lies with webkit's rendering implementation. Luckily there is a fix!

Currently you are animating the `margin-left` property of `#list_wrapper`, and this is what is causing the chop. So there is an easy work around and a better work around.

**EASY!**

Set `#list_wrapper` to `position:relative` with css and then animate the `left` property instead of `left-margin`. (actually margin-left will still work, but is not as good, so you COULD just use `position:relative` to fix this thang)

The downside here is its not very efficient for the browser (margin-left animation is pretty bad too)

**Better!**

Set the `#list_visible` to `position:relative` and set it's height appropriately (otherwise it will default to zero and your list will disappear). Then set the `#list_wrapper` to `position:absolute` and animate using the `left` property.

The advantage here, is that because we are animating an object that is `position:absolute`, it will not require a reflow of the entire document on each animation frame, making for much more efficient animation!

**BESTER!**

If you want to get fancy with it, you can look into css3 transitions and using `transform` to to move your slides. This will result in high fives from html5 people, as well has hardware acceleration when possible, (iPad animation will be smooth ect.), less cpu usage and other such niceties.

(Also is that you on the toilet?)

Comment: Awesome! Cheers for the detailed answer!

Comment: P.S.: That ain't me, that is @SimonGriffiths. I'm the website guy. :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed by clearfixing the enclosing ul, see http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

```
<div class="photoList">
  <ul class="clearfix">
  <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I added clearfix class that adds a "clear: both;" style to the node. Doesn't help though?

Comment: The problem is that webkit thinks `#photolist` is 0px tall because all your li's are floated.  If you think clearfix is an overkill just add `overflow: auto` to the `ul` and it will work (but you may get srollbars if the content doesn't fit).